# How to place n items on a circle with react native?

Tags: react-native

I want to place `n` items on a circle using `react native` but I don't know how to achieve that.
I tried to do this with `css` but I couldn't.
I want something like that : 
[image: placing items on a circle]

Could please anyone help me to do it ?

Comment: Cos and sin are your friends http://www.afralisp.net/archive/images/I4.GIF

Comment: yes the concept is right but i dont know how to manipulate react native view elements also.